# Unable to pass arguments to function used in add_action

Tags: php, functions, actions

I'm trying to pass a variable to be used in the function that's an arguement of add_action, like so.

```
$map_code = "test";
function insert_map_code_after_content($map_code){
    var_dump($map_code);
    echo(
    "
        <script id=\"google-maps\">
        </script>
    ");
};
add_action("after_content", "insert_map_code_after_content", 10, 1);
```

However, the var_dump just produces an empty string. How do I get it to output "test"?

Comment: Why does it need to be an argument? Where is the value coming from?

Comment: You may want to check the difference between `add_action` and `do_action` to understand why its not getting passed.

Comment: Jacob, I am trying to create a shortcode for a google map. The lat and lon get passed as attributes. Therefore, I'm generating the google map JS code on the fly and I store that in a variable. I need to use that variable, which contains the code.

Comment: This isn't code for a shortcode though. This is an action hook onto `after_content`, which isn't a standard wordpress hook. Do you want to create a shortcode like `[map lat="1234" lng="4321"]`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I created the after_content action myself in page.php. I'm basically trying to create multiple google maps on one page using shortcodes and attributes...if there are multiple, I slowly build up the JS code. Then, I output all of that at once after the content. So, I need to be able to pass that variable into my function, since it uses the shortcode atts.

Comment: You'll need a global variable then. In the shortcode, call `global $map_code;`, then add to it. Then in this hook, use `global $map_code;` to get all the code.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, that worked! If you put that as an answer, I'll accept : ). BTW I heard bad things about globals...is there any issues with using it here? Basically, I declared global $map_code in the shortcode (gets redeclared each time), then I use it again in the function (which is also a part of the shortcode, of course...all of this is in the same file)

Comment: Actually, I found another way: add_action('init', function() use($args) {
    //...
});